# UILabel doesn't show text on some some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

at one point I subclassed uilabel and use it in app. This was long ago and it works well. But now I run app on iphone 4s (ios 9.1) and this label show empty. I set the labels background to some color and it is positioned properly on the screen just as on all other devices, except there is no text inside. In debug I log the label and is tells me that the text is properly set.

```
<MainInstructions: 0x7fbbe2f77810; baseClass = UILabel; 
frame = (20 60.5; 280 39.5); 
text = 'Sign in or create a new a...'; 
opaque = NO;
autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; 
layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fbbe2f9b980>>
```

But on screen I only see this:
[image: empty label]

But it should be this:
[image]

Can somebody help me with this issue. The problem still remains even if I commented all the code inside subclass.

**UPDATE**

I found out if I remove the only property in header file the text is shown on screen. But its strange because this property is not used in any way, because I commented out all the code in .m file. Heres the header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainInstructions : UILabel
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lineSpacing;
@end
```

**SOLUTION**
the problem is with the property named lineSpacing, which is private property used by apple and in this way I overrode it by mistake.

Comment: May I ask why you subclassing UILabel? Just asking..

Comment: Can you also provide more of your code that we can see what else you doing? :P

Comment: I use it to set the leading for this label and then use this class on many places inside the storyboard.

Comment: I found the solution. I rename lineSpacing to just spacing and now everything works on all devices. Great but why was there a problem anyway. I still wonder ...

Comment: your solution ks true , if you use some name as you proprty , you will see this issue :)

Comment: My guess is that lineSpacing was added as a private property at some point (iOS9?), and by (re)declaring the property, you are overriding the getter and setter.

Comment: Followup:  Using the debugger, I confirmed that UILabel (now) has a property called lineSpacing.  To see it, add a symbolic breakpoint with the symbol `lineSpacing`.  Run the app in the debugger, and you'll see Xcode fill in `UILabel lineSpacing` as one of the breakpoints.

Comment: Great. It funny that the same label works on any other device, just iphone 4s has a problem with it.